# SQL query for rolling changes

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

1) Table name: period

```
+----------+  
| PeriodID |  
+----------+  
|        1 |  
|        2 |  
|        3 |  
|        4 |  
+----------+
```

2) Table name: value

```
+-------------+--------+  
| StartPeriod | Amount |  
+-------------+--------+  
|           1 |    100 |  
|           3 |    200 |  
+-------------+--------+
```

The first table represents time periods, like months. The second table represents the amount for each month, but only when it's different from the previous month. The amount starts at 100, stays at 100 for period 2, then jumps up to 200 beginning in period 3, and stays at 200 after that.

I need a query (MySQL) to return the amount for each period, like so:

```
+----------+--------+  
| PeriodID | Amount |  
+----------+--------+  
|        1 |    100 |  
|        2 |    100 |  
|        3 |    200 |  
|        4 |    200 |  
+----------+--------+
```

So the query would return the Amount for the latest StartPeriod in the value table that's less than or equal to the PeriodID. For example, for PeriodID 2 it returns the Amount for StartPeriod 1 because there is no value for StartPeriod2 and 1 is the largest number less than or equal to 2 that has an Amount in the value table.

(Sorry the tables are so ugly)

Thank you!

Comment: Why not add records for things like startPeriod = 2, amount = 100?  It seems sort of silly to have to rely on more complex query constructs because you have not set up your data to allow for effective querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT PeriodID, 
       (SELECT Amount
       FROM Value
       WHERE StartPeriod <= PeriodID
       ORDER BY StartPeriod DESC LIMIT 1) AS Amount
FROM Period AS p
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/474da/1)

Using variables probably performs better compared to the correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT PeriodID, 
       @amount := IF(Amount IS NOT NULL, Amount, @amount) AS Amount
FROM (    
   SELECT PeriodID, Amount
   FROM Period AS p
   LEFT JOIN Value AS v ON p.PeriodID = v.StartPeriod) AS t   
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @amount := -1) AS var
ORDER BY PeriodID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdb32/1)

Comment: These both work perfectly. I'm having trouble following the second one, though, can you explain? How is the IF statement working when it's defining the @amount variable using @amount? And what does the -1 do?

Comment: @gcblmnop Variables work on a row-by-row basis. Row order processing is  defined by `ORDER BY` clause. Hence, initially `@amount` is initialised to `-1`. `IF` function assigns `Amount` to `@amount` once a `NOT NULL` value is met, otherwise `@amount` is set equal to `@amount` of the *previous* row. This way, `NOT NULL` `Amount` values propagate down the row chain up-to the next row having a `NOT NULL` `Amount` value.

Answer (score 1):

A simple subselect that selects the value for the highest startperiod lower or equal to the period-id could achive that:

```
select
  periodid,
  (select amount from value where startperiod <= periodid order by startperiod desc limit 1)
from period
order by periodid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f29c/3